# Writing to mmap file with an offset, possibly dealing with endianess

Tags: c++, mmap, endianness

I am implementing a function that write to a memory mapped file given an offset.
The minimalist interpretation of the code is following:

```
MappedFile::MappedFile(int numOfItems, char * fname){
    pageSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);

    // Stretch the file size to the size of the (mmapped) array
    size_t newsize = numOfItems*sizeof(int) + 1; // + \0 null character

    if (lseek(fd, newsize-1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
    {
        //below is not good practice. See comment for explanation.
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (write(fd, "", 1) == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((mapBuffer = (char *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(int) * numOfItems, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("Error mapping file");
        exit(0);
    }

}

void MappedFile::setItem(int index, int value){
    //have problem here
    mapBuffer[index*sizeof(int)] = value;
}

int MappedFile::getItem(int index){
    return *((int *)(mapBuffer + index*sizeof(int));
}
```

The class maps a large number of integers into a binary file. The problem is `setItem` and `getItem` **does not always set/get the same value**. For example:

```
MappedFile intarr(2000, "Test.bin");
intarr.setItem(5, 220);
cout << intarr.getItem(5) << endl;
```

will print `220`. However,

```
MappedFile intarr(2000, "Test.bin");
intarr.setItem(5, 2200);
cout << intarr.getItem(5) << endl;
```

will print `152`.

I suspect this has something to do with endianess. I tried the following:

```
mapBuffer[index*sizeof(int)] = ntohl(value); //for setItem

return htonl(*((int *)(mapBuffer + index*sizeof(int))); //for getItem
```

but `getItem` always return 0.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but never check `errno` (which includes calling `perror`) after another system call, always check it as soon as possible. The state of `errno` after a successful system call (like, for example, a successful `close` call) is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg I mentioned your comment in the code.

Comment: exit() getting called in a constructor?! 
No RAII for the file descriptor?!
A pointer to a writeable string?!
Are you aware that we have 2015?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big problem is that you treat a pointer to `char` as a pointer to `int`, and those are not the same thing. If you want the mapped memory to store integers, then have a pointer to `int` and use normal array indexing.

So something like

```
int* mapBuffer = static_cast<int*>(mmap(...));
mapBuffer[someIndex] = someIntValue;
```

---

To be more precise, the following assignment will *truncate* your integer to fit in a `char`:

```
mapBuffer[index*sizeof(int)] = value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Only one thing: since `mmap(2)` is `void *` type, wouldn't `static_cast` be preferred?

Answer (score 2):

mapBuffer is a char* - so you're only able to write the low 8 bits of the int to it. 2200 in hex is 0x898 and 152 is 0x98, so you lost the upper byte(s). Upgrade the pointer to an int* and drop the *sizeof(int) from your get/set.

Comment: Thanks, I see where the problem is. I like your SP profile picture!